# Eloquent query get relationship value for every result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get the value of a column from another table based on the ID of my current query, and apply this to all my results.

These are my relationships:

Model "AttributeOption"

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attribute');
}
```

Model "Attributes"

```
public function attributeOptions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AttributeOption');
}
```

I have my result set as an array

```
$attributeResults = Attribute::whereIn('group_id', $attributes)->get()->toArray();
```

Heres a sample of my result from the query -

```
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 13
    "group_id" => 11
    "label" => "Food item"
    "type" => 1
    "value" => null
    "created_at" => "2018-04-08 20:49:26"
    "updated_at" => "2018-04-08 20:49:26"
  ]
```

Using the `type` column I want to look up the relationship using that value. I tried to run a test `dd($attributeResults[0]->option)`

Is there something I can do to my Eloquent query to get the relationship value during the query? I don't understand how you can do a relationship look up when its no longer an object, in this case, an array.

**Update DB Tables**

where the result `type = 1` I want to look up on the `attribute_options` table and find the id that matches in this case 'text'.

Attribute_options table

```
id : 1
option : text
```

Attribute table

```
id : 13
group_id : 11
label : food item
type : 1
value : null
```

Comment: what is the relationship of `type`?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly you want after query?

Comment: And Update tables also

Comment: Updated with tables and example data

Comment: "Is there something I can do to my Eloquent query to get the relationship value during the query?" Have you tried to use `with->('attributeOptions')` in the query? And about the second part I guess that you can use whereHas. More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if the naming convention is followed, we are not required to override the foreign and local keys when defining the relationship. That's if you have `AttributeOption` and `Attribute` Model, and the relationship is `AttributeOption` **has many** `Attribute`, then the foreign key of `Attribute` is `attribute_option_id`. In this case, since `type` is used as foreign key, and the relationship should be defined as follows:

**AttributeOption.php**

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attribute', 'type');
}
```

**Attribute.php**

```
public function attributeOption()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AttributeOption', 'type');
}
```

To get the relationships, retrieve the `attributes` models for a `AttributeOption` by accessing the `attributes` "dynamic property", for example:

```
AttributeOption::first()->attributes // collection of Attribute model
Attribute::first()-> attributeOption // AttributeOption model
```

`with` can be used to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationships:

```
$attributeResults = Attribute::with('attributeOption')
    ->whereIn('group_id', $attributes)
    ->get(); // collection of attribute model

foreach ($attributeResults as $attributeResult) {
    $attributeOption = $attributeResult->attributeOption;
    ...
}
```